# fopen returning NULL when trying to open a file from argv

Tags: c

My problem is that fopen returns NULL when using `argv[1]`. I am using code blocks and have set program arguments to the file I want to open. It is working if I use the file name directly in fopen, like this

```
infilep = fopen("map1.map","r");
```

The code so far can be found below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
//  printf("%d\n",argc);
//  printf("%s\n",argv[0]);
//  printf("%s\n",argv[1]);
    FILE* infilep;
    infilep = fopen("argv[1]","r");
    if(infilep==NULL){
        printf("ERROR: Can not open file");
    }

return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds funny, but I believe there was another question (in the last quarter or so) with the identical 'double quotes around an `argv[n]` name'.  The difficulty will be identifying that, especially since there's a moderate chance it has been closed as a trivial syntax error.  I can't spot it with a search that was listing sensible questions and answers, so it probably did get deleted.

Answer (score 2):

```
infilep = fopen("argv[1]","r");
```

Should be

```
infilep = fopen(argv[1],"r");
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
infilep = fopen("argv[1]","r");
```

Should be:

```
infilep = fopen(argv[1],"r");
```

Comment: Ooops... duplicate :|